Constructing Positive semi-definite of Block Hermitian matrix
Consider a Block Matrix
$
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1&B&C&\cdots& \\
B&A_2&D&\cdots \\
C&D&A_3&\cdots \\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots \\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&A_n
\end{bmatrix}
$
where $A_i$ are symmetric positive semi definite matrices. $B,C,D,\cdots $ are diagonal matrices with non-negative elements. Are there constraints on $B,C,D,\cdots $s such that P is positive semi-definite.
I want to use P as a covariance matrix for a multivariate gaussian distribution. The construction involves combining n multivariate gaussian distribution whose covariance matrices are $A_1, A_2,\cdots, A_n$, s.t. $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d} \forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots n\}$ and the diagonal matrices ($B,C,D, \cdots$) explain how each component of one distribution is dependent on corresponding component of other distributions.
Are there constraints on the diagonal elements of $B,C,D,\cdots$ that can help me obtain a positive semi definite matrix.
NOTE: I have written the non-diagonal block matrices as B,C,D only to show that P is symmetric in block sense (but since they are diagonal, P is symmetric matrix).

There are certainly conditions on $B_i$ that would guarantee that $P$ will be positive semidefinite (for instance, $B_i = 0$ for all $i$), but it's not clear what kinds of conditions will be useful here unless you provide more context

Also, it is not clear what exactly the pattern is going from one block-row to the next. That is, it's not clear what "$\cdots$" means. For instance, are we meant to conclude that the second row is given by
$$
[B_1 \ \ A_2 \ \ B_{n+1}\ \ B_{n+2}\ \ \cdots \ \ B_{2n-1}]?
$$

@BenGrossmann I made edits to my question to make it clearer. I hope it is clearer now.

That helps a bit, but it would be useful to know what benefit you get from choosing something besides $B = C = D = \cdots = 0$

If any of the $A_i$ are not positive definite (i.e. are not invertible) and if that $A_i$ doesn't have any block-diagonal structure, then all the off-diagonal blocks in the corresponding row of $P$ will have to be zero.
